SoundCore P25i works on Ubuntu, but on Debian it disconnects and connects with the same sound settings. Why?
SoundCore P25i works on Ubuntu, but on Debian it disconnects and connects with the same sound settings. Why?
SoundCore P25i is a bluetooth headphone
Is there a package installed in Ubuntu that is not in Debian about this?
Both Ubuntu and Debian use pipewire
inxi -A:

Audio:
  Device-1: Intel Alder Lake PCH-P High Definition Audio driver: snd_hda_intel
  API: ALSA v: k6.8.12-amd64 status: kernel-api
  Server-1: PipeWire v: 1.0.7 status: active



Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
